# *Error: (null) Code:8004100E Source:(null) Do you want to stop debugging ?* error while running the following vb script

Tags: vbscript, command

Execution of following Vb-script leads to the **Error: (null) Code:8004100E Source:(null)** error

Program:- **' List Internet Explorer Summary Settings**

```
    strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & _
            "\root\cimv2\Applications\MicrosoftIE")

Set colIESettings = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from MicrosoftIE_Summary")

For Each strIESetting in colIESettings
    Wscript.Echo "Active printer: " & strIESetting.ActivePrinter
    Wscript.Echo "Build: " & strIESetting.Build
    Wscript.Echo "Cipher strength: " & strIESetting.CipherStrength
    Wscript.Echo "Content advisor: " & strIESetting.ContentAdvisor
    Wscript.Echo "IE Administration Kit installed: " & _
        strIESetting.IEAKInstall
    Wscript.Echo "Language: " & strIESetting.Language
    Wscript.Echo "Name: " & strIESetting.Name
    Wscript.Echo "Path: " & strIESetting.Path
    Wscript.Echo "Product ID: " & strIESetting.ProductID
    Wscript.Echo "Version: " & strIESetting.Version
Next
```

Error:-

---

### VbsEdit 64-bit

Line:   5
Column: 1
Error:  (null)
Code:   8004100E
Source: (null)

### Do you want to stop debugging ?

### Yes   No

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Looks like this call is returning null, see if you can find out why that is happening. Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & _
        "\root\cimv2\Applications\MicrosoftIE")

Comment: I am new to Vb-script, in fact this is my first vb-script. please help&guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Error 8004100E means "invalid namespace". Starting with Windows Vista the namespace `root\cimv2\Applications\MicrosoftIE` has been removed from WMI.

Comment: I am executing this code in **Windows 7** machine, in-order to overcome this issue what I have to do. can you suggest me few better sites to learn Vb-script.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything simple providing the same set of information. Also, SO is not the right place to teach you VBScript basics. Use your preferred search engine to search for VBScript tutorials.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I did not get what you are saying. How to solve this issue? If they have removed then what should I do? I am facing a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831326/application-pool-status-in-iis-7?noredirect=1#comment27780334_18831326

Comment: @rapsalands Your problem is different from this.